# I have an aspx page within a folder which gives an error when clicked on through the menu link

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

The problem I have is that an aspx page within a folder called Masters doesn't open when I click to it through the menu link. The error i receive is that the URL http://ATT1/masters/masters/axy.aspx, is not found. My code is:

```
<body onload=" $(document).ready(function ()">
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <div class="page" id="container">
    <div class="header" >
        <div class="title">
            My ASP.NET Application
        </div>
        <div class="loginDisplay">
            <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" id="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a>
                    ]
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    Welcome <span class="bold">
                        <asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" />
                    </span>! [
                    <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out"
                        LogoutPageUrl="~/" />
                    ]
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
        </div>
        <div class="nav" style="background-color: #dedede; height: 25px">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li>Master
                    <ul class="nav first">

                        <li><a href="Masters/Employee_Details.aspx">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image39" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/icons/a_g.gif" />Compaines</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Masters/Master_setting.aspx">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image41" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/b_i.gif" />Master Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Masters/Mail_Setting.aspx">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image42" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/email.png" />Mail Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Masters/Shift_List.aspx">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image40" runat="server" ImageUrl="icons/device.gif" />Shift Details</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Masters/Shift%20Calender%20List%20.aspx">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image43" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/oCalendar.gif" />Shift
                            Calenders</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Masters/Shift_Roster_List.aspx">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image44" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/oCalendar.gif" />Shift
                            Rosters</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Masters/Shift_Group.aspx">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image45" runat="server" ImageUrl="icons/device.gif" />Shift Group</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Masters/Leave_Type_List.aspx">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image46" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/b_g.gif" />Leave Types</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Masters/Employee_Category.aspx">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image47" runat="server" ImageUrl="icons/oTasks.gif" />Employees Categories</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image48" runat="server" ImageUrl="icons/holiday.gif" />Public Holidays</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image49" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/b_b.gif" />Departments</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image50" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/b_c.gif" />Departments
                            Shifts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image51" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/b_a.gif" />Employees</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image52" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/b_h.gif" />Employees Shifts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image53" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/b_d.gif" />Employees Leave
                            Entries</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image54" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/b_d.gif" />Employees OutDoor
                            Entries</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image55" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/BackupDataBase.gif" />Attendence
                            Log</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image56" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/BackupDataBase.gif" />Manage
                            Work Code</a>
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li><a href="">Work Code</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Work Code Wise Daily Report</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Work Code Wise Summary Report</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Device Management</a>
                    <ul class="nav first">
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image57" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/Device.gif" />Device List</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image58" runat="server" ImageUrl="icons/logs.gif" />Employee Device
                            Logs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image59" runat="server" ImageUrl="icons/device.gif" />Device Commands</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image60" runat="server" ImageUrl="icons/device.gif" />Device Operation
                            Logs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image61" runat="server" ImageUrl="icons/device.gif" />Device Error
                            Messages</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Utilities</a>
                    <ul class="nav first">
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image62" runat="server" ImageUrl="icons/import.gif" />Import Employees
                            Details</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image63" runat="server" ImageUrl="icons/import.gif" />Import EmployeesOtherDetails</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image64" runat="server" ImageUrl="icons/export.gif" />Export Employees
                            Details</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image65" runat="server" ImageUrl="icons/export.gif" />Export Employees
                            Other Details</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image66" runat="server" ImageUrl="icons/export.gif" />Export Employees
                            Leave Details</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image67" runat="server" ImageUrl="icons/import.gif" />Import Employees
                            Leave Balance</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image68" runat="server" ImageUrl="icons/import.gif" />Import Log
                            Records</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image70" runat="server" ImageUrl="icons/import.gif" />Parallel Database
                            Export</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image69" runat="server" ImageUrl="icons/import.gif" />Export Attendence
                            Logs</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Reports</a>
                    <ul class="nav first">
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image71" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/c_c.gif" />Recalculate
                            Attendence</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image72" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/c_c.gif" />Daily Attendence
                            Report</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image73" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/c_c.gif" />Monthly Status</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image74" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/c_c.gif" />Yearly Summary</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image75" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/c_c.gif" />Attendence
                            Sumary Report</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image76" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/c_c.gif" />Leave Summary</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image77" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/c_c.gif" />Employees Details</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image78" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/c_c.gif" />Employees Shift
                            Scheduler</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image79" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/c_c.gif" />Department
                            Summary</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image80" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/c_c.gif" />Log Records</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image81" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/c_c.gif" />Random Check
                            Report</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image82" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/c_c.gif" />Leave Entry
                            Report</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image83" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/c_c.gif" />OutDoor Entry
                            Report</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image84" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/c_c.gif" />Daily Log Report
                            Matrix</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image85" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/c_c.gif" />Last Day Status
                            Report</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image86" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/c_c.gif" />Continuous
                            Abnormality</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image87" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/c_c.gif" />Muster Roll
                            Report</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image88" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/c_c.gif" />Form J Report</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image89" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/c_c.gif" />Detailed Form
                            J Report</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image90" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/c_c.gif" />Generate memo</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image91" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/c_c.gif" />Special Reports</a>
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li><a href="">Departments vs EmploymentType Matrix</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Company vs EmploymentType Matrix</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Department Graph</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Company Graph</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image92" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/c_c.gif" />Export Logs</a>
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li><a href="">Export Attendence Logs</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Attendence Logs (Employee Wise)</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Export Device Logs</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Export Logs in Custom Format</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Logs in Third Party Payroll Format</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">SAP P10/ P20 Export</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">
                            <asp:Image ID="Image93" runat="server" ImageUrl="easymenu/c_c.gif" />Extra Reports</a>
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li><a href="">Custom Monthly Status Report</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Monthly Late Arrival Early Departure Report</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">System User</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Database Setting</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Change Password</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a>
                    <ul class="nav first">
                        <li><a href="">Help Manual</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Extend Evaluation</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Logoff</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div style="background-image: url('images/title2.jpg ')">
            <asp:Image ID="Image36" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/header_divider.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/a_a.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/header_divider.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/a_d.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image5" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/header_divider.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/a_e.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image6" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/header_divider.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image7" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/b_i.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image8" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/header_divider.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image9" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/a_c.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image10" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/header_divider.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image11" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/b_b.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image12" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/header_divider.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image13" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/icons/holiday.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image15" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/icons/device.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image14" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/header_divider.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image17" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/oCalendar.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image16" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/header_divider.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image19" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/icons/oTasks.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image18" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/header_divider.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image21" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/b_g.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image20" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/header_divider.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image23" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/b_c.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image22" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/header_divider.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image25" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/b_a.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image24" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/header_divider.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image27" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/b_h.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image26" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/header_divider.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image29" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/b_f.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image28" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/header_divider.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image31" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/b_f.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image30" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/header_divider.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image33" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/icons/logs.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image32" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/header_divider.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image35" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/BackupDataBase.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image34" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/header_divider.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image37" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/a_g.gif" />
            <asp:Image ID="Image38" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/easymenu/header_divider.gif" />
        </div>            
        <%--<a class="vlightbox1" href="" title="10" id="firstImage">
        <img src="images/calender.jpg" alt="10"/></a>--%>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>     
    <div id="popup_box" style="width:445px; margin-top:50px; margin-left:50px" >
        <table id="" style="width:445px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  align="center">
        <tr>
        <td style="background-color:#0099CC; height:25px">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=" Login Form"></asp:Label><a id="popupBoxClose">Close</a></td>            
        </tr>
            <tr style="font-size: 0;">               
                <td>
                    <img src="images/login-header.gif" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-left: 30px; padding-top: 20px;" align="left">
                    <table id="" cellpadding="1px" style="width:350px;" >
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:100px;" align="right">
                                <b><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Login Name"></asp:Label></b></td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_LoginName" runat="server" Width="210px"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <b><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label></b></td>
                            <td  align="left">                                    
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Txt_Password"  runat="server" TextMode="Password"  Width="210px"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td colspan="2"  align="right"  >
                        <table id="" width="100%"><tr><td>
                  <%--    <cc1:captchacontrol id="CaptchaControl1" runat="server" CaptchaChars="ACDEFGHJKLNPQRTUVXYZ2346789" CaptchaMinTimeout="3" ErrorMessage="" Text="Enter the code shown:"></cc1:captchacontrol>--%></td><td><asp:ValidationSummary  ID="ValidationSummary2" runat="server" Visible="False"  />
                       </td></tr></table>
                        </td></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" colspan="2" >
                            <table>
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_InValidError" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/login_btn.jpg" />
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: `Masters/Employee_Details.aspx` indicates that you have one more folder `Masters`, so you should be fine once you remove `Masters` from the url

Answer (score 0):

If the page that you have shown as an example is in the Masters folder, then links on it will be relative to that folder.

href="Masters/Master_setting.aspx" would give "Masters/Masters/Master_setting.aspx"

So as the V4Vendetta's comment said, remove the Masters from the relative link, or use an absolute link such as href="~/Masters/Master_setting.aspx"